# Member "owner" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in type

Tags: solidity-0.5.x

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract reeler{
  uint public id;
  string public name;
  string public addres;
  string public state;
  string public pincode;
  uint public yarncount = 0;
  mapping(uint => Yarn) public yarns;
  
  struct Yarn{
    address payable owner; 
    uint yid;
    string types;
    string weight;
    uint price;
    string colour; 
  }

  event YarnCreated(
    address payable owner,
    uint yid, 
    string types,
    string weight,
    uint price,
    string colour
  );
  event YarnPurchased(
    address payable owner,
    uint yid, 
    string types,
    string weight,
    uint price,
    string colour
  );
    constructor() public {
    id= 1098;
    name="joy";
    addres="mysore";
    state="karnataka";
    pincode="560043";
    /*types="thread";
    weight= 80;
    rate= 1000;
    colour= "lilac";*/
    }

  function  createYarn(string memory types, string memory weight, uint price, string memory colour) public {
        //make sure parameters are correct
        //require valid name
        require(bytes(types).length > 0);
        //require valid weight
        require(bytes(weight).length > 0);
        //require valid price
        require(price > 0);
        //require valid clour
        require(bytes(colour).length > 0);
         //increment product count
        yarncount ++;
        //create product
        yarns[yarncount]= Yarn(msg.sender,yarncount, types, weight, price, colour);
        //trigger event
        emit YarnCreated(msg.sender, yarncount, types, weight, price, colour);
        
  }
  function purchaseYarn(uint yid) public payable {
    // fetch the product
    Yarn memory yarn= yarns[yid];
    //fetch the owner
    address payable seller = Yarn.owner;
    //make sure the yarn is valid
    //purchase it
    Yarn.owner = msg.sender;
    //update the product
    Yarn[yid]= Yarn;
    //pay the seller by ethers
    address(seller).transfer(msg.value);
    //trigger event
    emit YarnPurchased(msg.sender, yarncount, Yarn.types, Yarn.weight, Yarn.price, Yarn.colour);
  }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from the `purchaseYarn` function where there is a confusion between the `Yarn` struct type and the `yarn` struct instance.

This code works :

```
  function purchaseYarn(uint yid) public payable {
// fetch the product
Yarn memory yarn= yarns[yid];
//fetch the owner
address payable seller = yarn.owner;
//make sure the yarn is valid
//purchase it
yarn.owner = msg.sender;
//update the product
//pay the seller by ethers
address(seller).transfer(msg.value);
//trigger event
emit YarnPurchased(msg.sender, yarncount, yarn.types, yarn.weight, yarn.price, yarn.colour);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable name is **yarn**. But you are trying to access **Yarn.owner**.
You should change it to **yarn.owner**.
There are several similar typos in the same function that you should change too.